# Passing a service as parameter to another service

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I have a request service and I want to get tenant's address with its id. So I need TenantAppService in another service. I can't pass it from javascript, because it is an object and I think ajax converts my parameters to url. Do I need to serialize it or can I create an instance of TenantAppService in my service? Is there an applicable constructor?

Or can I use stored procedure? I tried it but even though i imported

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

SqlConnection could not be found.

Comment: https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dependency-Injection

Comment: [Should I be calling an AppService from another AppService?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46653370/8601760)