# What is the purpose of using both Application Service and Manager?

Tags: asp.net, domain-driven-design, aspnetboilerplate, application-design, dddd

I'm not an experienced programmer. I always browse the source codes to learn some things. ASP.NET Boilerplate is my favorite one. Yesterday, I noticed there is friendship application service (in service/application layer) and friendship manager (in business/domain layer). I didn't understand why there is friendship manager. Friendship service isn't enough?

```
public interface IFriendshipAppService : IApplicationService
{
    Task<FriendDto> CreateFriendshipRequest(CreateFriendshipRequestInput input);

    Task<FriendDto> CreateFriendshipRequestByUserName(CreateFriendshipRequestByUserNameInput input);

    void BlockUser(BlockUserInput input);

    void UnblockUser(UnblockUserInput input);

    void AcceptFriendshipRequest(AcceptFriendshipRequestInput input);
}
```

```
public interface IFriendshipManager : IDomainService
{
    void CreateFriendship(Friendship friendship);

    void UpdateFriendship(Friendship friendship);

    Friendship GetFriendshipOrNull(UserIdentifier user, UserIdentifier probableFriend);

    void BanFriend(UserIdentifier userIdentifier, UserIdentifier probableFriend);

    void AcceptFriendshipRequest(UserIdentifier userIdentifier, UserIdentifier probableFriend);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation on [NLayer-Architecture](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/NLayer-Architecture):

> The application layer ... perform[s] requested application functionalities. It uses Data Transfer Objects to get data from and return data to the presentation or distributed service layer. ...
>
> The domain layer ... perform[s] business/domain logic. ...

Here's what that means, in high-level comments:

```
// IFriendshipManager implementation

public void CreateFriendshipAsync(Friendship friendship)
{
    // Check if friending self. If yes, then throw exception.
    // ...

    // Insert friendship via repository.
    // ...
}
```

```
// IFriendshipAppService implementation

public Task<FriendDto> CreateFriendshipRequest(CreateFriendshipRequestInput input)
{
    // Check if friendship/chat feature is enabled. If no, then throw exception.
    // ...

    // Check if already friends. If yes, then throw exception.
    // ...

    // Create friendships via IFriendshipManager.
    // ...

    // Send friendship request messages.
    // ...

    // Return a mapped FriendDto.
    // ...
}
```

Notice that the concerns (and resulting actions) in `AppService` and `Manager` are subtly different.

A `Manager` is meant to be reused by an `AppService`, another `Manager`, or other parts of code.

For example, `IFriendshipManager` can be used by:

- `ChatMessageManager`
- `ProfileAppService`
- `TenantDemoDataBuilder`

On the other hand, an `AppService` should **not** be called from another `AppService`.

See: [Should I be calling an AppService from another AppService?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46653370/8601760)

Comment: "On the other hand, an AppService should not be called from another AppService."

This sentence was very explanatory. I got it. I've had this problem in my demo applications. Call service from the service.

Thank you very much for correction and answer. Have a nice day.