# Service call to service at Aspnet Zero Boilerplate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-boilerplate

I have a couple of simple services that exchange information:

```
public class Service2: PPlusAppServiceBase
    {

        private readonly IAbpSession _session;

        public Service2(IAbpSession session)
        {
            _session = session;
        }

        public Entity getEntity()
        {
            Entity et = new Entity();
            Service1 _service1 = new Service1(_session);

            [...]
            _service1.getEntity();
            [...]

            return et;
        }

    }
```

```
 public class Service1: PPlusAppServiceBase
    {
        private readonly IAbpSession _session;

        public Service1(IAbpSession session)
        {
            _session = session;
        }

        public Entity getEntity()
        {
            _session.[...]
            return et;
        }

    }
```

OK, it works properly and I just have to send the session to work. But how can I do it simply when I have to get information from a more complex service? Like the default Boilerplate? For example, `EditionAppService`:

```
public class EditionAppService : PPlusAppServiceBase, IEditionAppService
    {
        private readonly EditionManager _editionManager;
        private readonly IRepository<SubscribableEdition> _editionRepository;
        private readonly IRepository<Tenant> _tenantRepository;
        private readonly IBackgroundJobManager _backgroundJobManager;

        public EditionAppService(
            EditionManager editionManager,
            IRepository<SubscribableEdition> editionRepository,
            IRepository<Tenant> tenantRepository,
            IBackgroundJobManager backgroundJobManager)
        {
            _editionManager = editionManager;
            _editionRepository = editionRepository;
            _tenantRepository = tenantRepository;
            _backgroundJobManager = backgroundJobManager;
        }

        [AbpAuthorize(AppPermissions.Pages_Editions)]
        public async Task<ListResultDto<EditionListDto>> GetEditions()
        {
            var editions = await (from edition in _editionRepository.GetAll()
                                  join expiringEdition in _editionRepository.GetAll() on edition.ExpiringEditionId equals expiringEdition.Id into expiringEditionJoined
                                  from expiringEdition in expiringEditionJoined.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      Edition = edition,
                                      expiringEditionDisplayName = expiringEdition.DisplayName
                                  }).ToListAsync();

            var result = new List<EditionListDto>();

            foreach (var edition in editions)
            {
                var resultEdition = ObjectMapper.Map<EditionListDto>(edition.Edition);
                resultEdition.ExpiringEditionDisplayName = edition.expiringEditionDisplayName;

                result.Add(resultEdition);
            }

            return new ListResultDto<EditionListDto>(result);
        }
    }
```

As you can see, the constructor is more complex, the constructor data comes directly defined by `swagger` (`ASP.NET Boilerplate` creates dynamic drivers and `swagger`, and it is these that carry this data that they use as a builder), but when making the call from another service I can't get them.

What is the best way to do that is edit the minimum the second?

In `Service2`, where I have to call `EditionAppService.GetEditions` I need something like:

```
EditionAppService _editionAppService = new EditionAppService();
_editionAppService.GetEditions().Result;
```

But wait for the builder I don't have

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That design pattern is called [Dependency Injection](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dependency-Injection).

Do this instead:

```cs
public class Service2: PPlusAppServiceBase
{
    private readonly EditionAppService _editionAppService; // Add this
    private readonly Service1 _service1;                   // Add this
    private readonly IAbpSession _session;

    public Service2(
        EditionAppService editionAppService,               // Add this
        Service1 service1,                                 // Add this
        IAbpSession session)
    {
        _editionAppService = editionAppService;            // Add this
        _service1 = service1;                              // Add this
        _session = session;
    }

    public Entity getEntity()
    {
        Entity et = new Entity();
        // Service1 _service1 = new Service1(_session);    // Remove this

        // ...
        _service1.getEntity();
        // ...

        return et;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Related: [Should I be calling an AppService from another AppService?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46653370/8601760)